# Setting category for post as default

Tags: categories

How can I set a default category from posts that I create? I have tried modify setting options but have not been able to have the default category that I want show up. The current default is "uncategorized"

Comment: Why not just rename the uncategorized category to suit your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just recently did this with a custom post type and custom taxonomy with the following code.

```
function cpt_assign_term($post_id) {

    $current_post = get_post( $post_id );

    // Only apply to new posts.
    if ( $current_post->post_date == $current_post->post_modified ) {
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'default-term_name-or-id', 'category', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post_{your-post-type}', 'cpt_assign_term' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

Comment: Before setting a term to a post you should first check whether or not the post does not yet have this term attached ;-)